# Test suite failed to run TypeError: Invalid URL: http://localhost

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Invalid URL: http://localhost

      at new URLImpl (node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL-impl.js:21:13)
```

This error is coming randomly when I run RTL test cases using npm test

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the test cases that fail? The URL is perfectly valid, I suspect the RTL byte may be the culprit.

Comment: @DanielW. The same test cases are passing and randomly got failed and above error occurs. It is happening when the test file are increasing and test cases are around 100